# If I don't yet know a certain programming language but want a job which needs it, how can get any experience in it?

Tags: skills, learning

So I'm in the final year of my degree and I'm looking into jobs in robotics. It seems like the vast majority of them need knowledge of c++ which I don't currently have. Furthermore, so far all the jobs involving c++ I have seen so far require experience with it.

This seems like an impossible situation to me - can't get experience without experience. Is the only option really just taking a gap year or something after graduation to spend time learning the language?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/111881/how-much-do-i-need-to-learn-in-order-to-get-an-entry-level-asp-net-job/111883#111883

Comment: You've got at least half a year. You could assign yourself homework and start practicing... Or consider going into another field for a while that will give you more time to develop C++ skills (and who knows, you might decide that you like that field as much as robotics). Finally, remember that jobs which say they want experience in a particular may settle for someone who has proven skill in other languages which are structurally similar. (If you've worked in C and in Java, you can sorta average the two and have the general concept of C++, though there's a lot of detail to learn.)

Comment: And remember that anyone hiring right out of college KNOWS you don't have much job experience yet.

Comment: what is your degree? why hasn't it exposed you to C++ if it is a suitable subject for getting into robotics? what languages has it exposed you to?

Comment: Take a course. Maybe online. Maybe free.

Comment: In the case of C++ I'd read the interesting chapter's of Stroustrup's The C++ Language and then start coding.

Answer (score 2):

Learn it in your free time, each around a week:

- Data types and functions
- Classes and Objects
- Algorithms, iterate and sort lists

This should get you covered for interviews and understanding code.

Then look into robotics, what are common tasks there, what algorithms are used, is there a cheap robot to test stuff on, then try to solve a task like fetch your newspaper with it. You'll probably fail, but learn a lot.

Imagine taking 3-4 courses (basics to robotics) at university, but condensing them in a shorter timeframe and teaching yourself from books or blogs. That's what work life later will be anyway.

Usually when switching languages or technology, you have around 1-3 months in a company until you are expected to deliver working code. Not in depth, but good enough to know where to find answers.

Answer (score 2):

### Learn the skills

If you don't have any skills with C/C++, then most likely you're not ready for such jobs, and for most companies you shouldn't expect to learn the basics on the job - there would be enough product-specific things to learn, so they generally require general basic skills as a prerequisite.

### Languages are easy

That being said, gaining some proficiency in a language doesn't require that much time. It's often assumed that students in 3-4 year comp-sci programs will graduate already knowing multiple programming languages along with everything else they're doing, so 1 new language per year is possible as a side-effect of general learning. Getting up to speed in a new language is something that a qualified programmer should be able to do on their own within a couple months - the first project working in an unknown language would take more time, and that's it.

If it's your final year, you should be able to learn some C++ and build some trial projects before graduation, as a side-project along your other classes. Alternatively, it's something that should be doable in half a year while working in an unrelated programming job. If you feel that you would need to spend a whole gap year purely on that, then that's not a good sign about your capabilities (or self-esteem).